# How to reaload scala application after code change using actors and sbt

Tags: scala, sbt, akka, actor

```
object Main extends App {

  //val name: String = "Apka"
  val system = ActorSystem()
  val worker = system.actorOf(Props[Worker], name = "workerActor")

  worker ! "test"
  worker ! FetchUrl(new URL("http://google.com"))

  println("test")

  //Await.time

  val stopped: Future[Boolean] = gracefulStop(worker, 15 seconds)
  Await.result(stopped, 16 seconds)
  system.shutdown()
}
```

I am trying to test scala application with sbt and ~run option, but with this method system stops before all queues will be empty, and without it i must restart the whole sbt. Is there any way of stopping actor system after set perioid of time, or after all actor queues are empty?

Answer (score 4):

You should read this article as it describes a very good technique for graceful shutdown:

http://letitcrash.com/post/30165507578/shutdown-patterns-in-akka-2

But in summary, you basically set up a `Reaper` actor that is responsible for shutting down the system when all created actor instances have been stopped.  Each instance that is created registers itself with the reaper for `DeathWatch`.  Then, each actor can be sent a `PoisonPill` that will ensure they have processed all messages that arrived before the `PoisonPill` first before stopping.  When they all have stopped, the reaper kicks in and stops the `ActorSystem`.  A quick and dirty impl could look something like this:

```
case class WatchMe(ref: ActorRef)
class ShutdownReaper extends Actor {
  val watched = ArrayBuffer.empty[ActorRef]

  def receive = {
    case WatchMe(ref) =>
      context.watch(ref)      
      watched += ref
    case Terminated(ref) =>
      watched -= ref      
      if (watched.isEmpty) context.system.shutdown
  }
}

case class FetchUrl(url:URL)
class Worker extends Actor{
  override def preStart = {
    context.system.actorSelection("/user/reaper") ! WatchMe(context.self)
  }

  def receive = {
    case FetchUrl(url) =>
      //Do something here, sleeping to fake work
      Thread.sleep(5000)
  }
}

object ReaperTest{
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val system = ActorSystem("test")

    val reaper = system.actorOf(Props[ShutdownReaper], "reaper")
    val worker1 = system.actorOf(Props[Worker])
    val worker2 = system.actorOf(Props[Worker])

    worker1 ! FetchUrl(new URL("http://www.google.com"))
    worker2 ! FetchUrl(new URL("http://www.cnn.com"))

    worker1 ! PoisonPill
    worker2 ! PoisonPill
  }
}
```

Most of this code will look familiar from the post, but I simplified it a bit for brevity's sake.